# How to use AndroidStudio and DDMS Monitor with java 7

Tags: java, android, adb, ipv6, ddms

How to start AndroidStudio with java 6 instead of standart java 7 on Windows?

Avoiding DDMS Failed to initialize Monitor Thread: Unable to establish loopback connection?

Answer (score 0):

Click on menu item "Window" and select Preferences. In the popup search for java. There will be some entries displayed. Compiler allows you to set the java version being used.

To make sure that eclipse itself uses another version of java, you need to specify the link in the computer settings, I think it's called JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 0):

To start AndroidSudio with  desired JDK we can  use ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK Enviroment variable[image: Wow to Set this on Windows7].
To а Android DDMS (Monitor)  to use IPv4 we include

```
set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

in the monitor.bat [image: Sample piece of file]